# Sharp character within an \url{...}: allowed within all sectioning commands, except (sub)paragraphs

Tags: sectioning, urls

The `url`'s documentation claims `\url{...}`, if used in the argument to another
command, cannot have an argument containing any `%`, `#`, or `^^`, or ending
with `\` (though this can be bypassed by `\urldef`'s URLs, as shown below).

But it turns out that, if `\url{...}`'s argument contains `#` and is used within
the argument to a sectioning command:

- *strangely*: it works like a charm for `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`,
  `\subsubsection`,
- *very strangely*: it doesn't work for other sectioning commands: `\paragraph` and
  `\subparagraph` (very strange!). It fails with the error:

  > Illegal parameter number in definition of \@svsechd.

Do you see the reasons of theses discrepancies (especially the latter one)?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{url}

\urldef{\myparturl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#part}
\urldef{\mychapterurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#chapter}
\urldef{\mysectionurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#section}
\urldef{\mysubsectionurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subsection}
\urldef{\mysubsubsectionurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subsubsection}
\urldef{\myparagraphurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#paragraph}
\urldef{\mysubparagraphurl}\url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subparagraph}

\begin{document}

         \part[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/part}}
      \chapter[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/chapter}}
      \section[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/section}}
   \subsection[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/subsection}}
\subsubsection[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/subsubsection}}
    \paragraph[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/paragraph}}
 \subparagraph[No     sharp]{No     sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/subparagraph}}

         \part[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \myparturl}
      \chapter[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \mychapterurl}
      \section[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \mysectionurl}
   \subsection[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \mysubsectionurl}
\subsubsection[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \mysubsubsectionurl}
    \paragraph[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \myparagraphurl}
 \subparagraph[Not so sharp]{Not so sharp: \mysubparagraphurl}

         \part[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#part}}
      \chapter[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#chapter}}
      \section[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#section}}
   \subsection[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subsection}}
\subsubsection[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subsubsection}}
    \paragraph[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#paragraph}}
 \subparagraph[       Sharp]{       Sharp: \url{https://www.nowhere.org/#subparagraph}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You surely have observed that `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` are typeset inline.

Comment: @egreg Yes. Related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier if we analyze `\section*` and `\paragraph*`, but the reason for failure is the same as for the main commands.

If you do `\section*{x}`, LaTeX transforms this into

```
\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}*{x}
```

which does some bookkeeping and leaves

```
\@ssect{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{x}
```

It's not very different, up to this point, with `\paragraph*{x}`, where we get

```
\@ssect{\z@}{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{x}
```

The big difference is in the third argument, which is positive in the case of `\section` and negative in the case of `\paragraph`. LaTeX uses positive and negative to decide between displayed titles or inline ones.

Here's the definition of `\@ssect`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 5928:
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #4{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #1}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #5\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax #5}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#3}}
```

In the case of `\paragraph*{\url{#}}`, LaTeX tries to execute

```
\def\@svsechd{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries{\hskip\z@\relax\url{#}}
```

while in the `\section*{\url{#}}` case the code is

```
\begingroup
\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip\z@}\interline\@M
  \url{#}\@@par}%
\endgroup
```

The relevant tracing for `\section*{\url{#}}`:

```
\@ssect #1#2#3#4#5->\@tempskipa #3\relax \ifdim \@tempskipa >\z@ \begingroup #4
{\@hangfrom {\hskip #1}\interlinepenalty \@M #5\@@par }\endgroup \else \def \@s
vsechd {#4{\hskip #1\relax #5}}\fi \@xsect {#3}
#1<-\z@ 
#2<--3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex
#3<-2.3ex \@plus .2ex
#4<-\normalfont \Large \bfseries 
#5<-\url {##}
```

and from `\paragraph*{\url{#}}`

```
\@ssect #1#2#3#4#5->\@tempskipa #3\relax \ifdim \@tempskipa >\z@ \begingroup #4
{\@hangfrom {\hskip #1}\interlinepenalty \@M #5\@@par }\endgroup \else \def \@s
vsechd {#4{\hskip #1\relax #5}}\fi \@xsect {#3}
#1<-\z@ 
#2<-3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex
#3<--1em
#4<-\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries 
#5<-\url {##}

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@svsechd.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.11 \paragraph*{\url{#}}

?
```

The `#` is doubled in the tracing information, but becomes again `#` when doing the replacement of the arguments.

So in the `\section` case, `\url{#}` is called to typeset something, in the `\paragraph` case it is used in the body of a definition and the isolated `#` raises the error because it's illegal in a definition.

You get the same error with the simpler

```
\def\x{\url{#}}
```